# Read The value of listbox in loop and put in google map

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps, listbox

i am writing a certain code for showing multiple marker the google map. I Put all the value in a ListBox and trying read value in a loop and put it in map. I also write  javascript. But While i am reading through loop some error occours. i am writing windows form application .

```
Dim lat, lon As String
Dim finalstr As String
Dim latlongroup As String
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    Dim tempstr = ListBox1.Items.Item(i)
    If tempstr <> " " Then
        tempstr = ListBox1.Items(i)
    End If
    latlongroup = "{" & "tempstr:" & tempstr & " }"
    latlongroup = latlongroup & " , " & "{" & "tempstr:" & tempstr & " }"   
    finalstr = tb1.Text & vbCrLf & latlongroup
    finalstr = finalstr & tb2.Text
    Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = finalstr
Next
```

the java script part is

var markers = [

```
];
window.onload = function () {

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    var icon = "red";
    icon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/" + icon + ".png";
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
    });
    (function (marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    })(marker, data);
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    i++;
    if (i == markers.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    }
 }, 80);
 }
```